# Add textbox user input to buffer when appending data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a project in which I am making a terminal-like application on visual studio. I need a way to store the user's input while writing output simultaneously. It needs to be able to take commands that contain special characters as well. My first thought was to save what has been output and remove it from the text in the textbox, but then I came up with this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Terminal
{
    public partial class pnlTerminal : UserControl
    {
        public TextBox tbx;

        private string _inputBuffer;
        private List<int> _bufferLocation;

        public pnlTerminal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tbx = tbxTerminal;
            _inputBuffer = "";
            _bufferLocation = new List<int>();
        }

        private void tbxTerminal_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) && ((e.Modifiers & Keys.Shift) == 0))
            {
                //Send buffer
            }
        }

        private void tbxTerminal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            _inputBuffer += e.KeyChar;
            _bufferLocation.Add(tbxTerminal.TextLength);
        }

        private void tbxTerminal_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //If backspace was just pressed then check if any buffered characters were deleted and remove them
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
            {
                if (_bufferLocation[_bufferLocation.Count - 1] >= tbxTerminal.TextLength)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _bufferLocation.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (_bufferLocation[i] >= tbxTerminal.TextLength)
                        {
                            _inputBuffer = _inputBuffer.Substring(0, i);
                            i = _bufferLocation.Count;
                            Console.WriteLine(_inputBuffer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

It feels like there should be a better way, but I can't think of any and as far as I can tell this solution does work. Thank you.